# convert string field to an array field in monogodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a following attributes in an array I want to convert that attribute in to an array 
I have following structure
**data collection**

```
{
 retailer: ObjectId('55c49f09e749022be54c51bb'),
 function: execute,
 value: 20
}
```

I want to update it in following order which will have name and status under the retailer.

```
{
    retailer: {
        id: ObjectId('55c49f09e749022be54c51bb'),
        name: welcome,
        status : 2
    },
    function: execute,
    value: 20
}
```

**retailer collection**

```
  {
    _id : ObjectId('55c49f09e749022be54c51bb'),
    name : 'welcome',
    status : 2,
    is_active: true
  }
```

Can u tell me how can I put the retailer collection values inside the data collection

Comment: You use PHP right? These are not arrays ( PHP calls everything arrays ) but object structures instead. It is also entirely unclear where the additional property values are meand to come from. Do you just want to update all objects in your collection with the same information? Or is there some rule that should be applied to the update?

Comment: I am using python, and I have to upsert few fields inside only retailer, not I have to update the entire document

Comment: Please stop using terms you clearly do not understand. Not an array, not an upsert. I asked you a clear question to please explain where the properties not present in the document are meant to come from. Explaining the restructing is easy, but if you cannot explain where the other values are meant to come from then any answer will not be correct. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32841173/edit) link on your question and make it better.

Comment: I hope that will give u sufficient information.

Comment: So to be clear about this ( note that this is how you are supposed to ask a question ), the facts are you actually have **two** collections and now you want to update all of the information in one of them that previously just has the `_id` value from the other collection with the full object from that referenced collection instead. Right? Can you perhaps think of just using those terms in both your question body and title? Again, same [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32841173/edit) link. Welcome to StackOverflow and also learning how to ask for what you want.